# SecurityException while connecting using Jsoup

Tags: android, jsoup

I making a small Android app to search images on Google Images using my app.
Initially i was testing to print the images `src` in a `TextView`.
But the app stops by raising a `SecruityException`.

```
package com.example.googleimages;



import java.io.IOException;
import org.jsoup.Jsoup;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Document;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Element;
import org.jsoup.select.Elements;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ProgressBar;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener {
    ProgressBar progress;
    Button btn;
    EditText searchtext;
    Document doc;
    TextView tv;
    String src;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        initialize();
        btn.setOnClickListener(this);


    }

    private void initialize() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        progress=(ProgressBar)findViewById(R.id.progressBar1);
        btn=(Button)findViewById(R.id.search);
        searchtext=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.searchText);
        tv=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView1);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        progress.setVisibility(0);
        for(int i=0;i<100;i+=20)
        progress.setProgress(i);

        Thread browser=new Thread(){
            public void run(){
        try {
            doc=Jsoup.connect("http://www.google.com.my/imghp?hl=en&tab=wi").data("q",searchtext.getText().toString())
                    .data("btnG","Search by image").userAgent("Mozilla").get();

            Elements elements=doc.getElementsByTag("img");
            for(Element e:elements){
                src=e.attr("src");
                tv.setText(tv.getText()+src+"\n");
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
            }
        };
        browser.start();

    }

}
```

Comment: have you added internet permission in manifest?

Comment: @Raghunandan:OK I defined it and it solved the problem but now the source url of images are not getting displayed in the textview but instead after few seconds the application crashes.

Comment: then there is a problem with jsoup parsing. check it and you should be able to get the urls displayed